# How can I export animationclip data from unity's assetbundle file?

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, assetbundle

AssetBundle files of unity contain various types of data, such as mesh, texture and animation, etc. I want to export the mesh and animation data from an assetbundle file into common use format such as .fbx, then I can load the data into Android platform and implement the skeletal animation using JAVA. With the help of Unity Studio, I can export the mesh data from assetbundle file into .fbx format file. However, I can not find any animation data from the exported .fbx file. After exporing an assetbundle file using Unity Studio, I found that the animation data that I want to export is stored using animationclip type. However, the Unity Studio only supports exporting the raw file, which is .dat format. I have no idea how to parse this file outside using Java or C++. So my question is, how can I export the animationclip data from assetbundle into ASCII file, or how can I export fbx models from assetbundles with animation? I would be greatly appreciated if someone could help me.

Comment: This is a proprietary and closed file format. Unless you work for Unity, have Unity's source code or you are very good at reverse-engineering, it would be impossible to do this without Unity's API.

Comment: Oh no, it is such a depressing result.  It seems I have to learn the Unity's API. Thanks you very much @Programmer.

Comment: No problem. Unity is easy to learn and you can find many resources out there when you Google them